# ExtJS Ajax Call Fails 404

Tags: ajax, extjs

If I load the "Request URL" on the browser, it shows the JSON code, so it's loading fine. The Ajax query below keeps failing with 404 error.

I am not highly knowledged in AJAX calls, I did search on Google as well as here about this problem and I was not able to find an answer.

```
Request URL: ******
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: ******
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:1841
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2018 16:48:06 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer ******
Origin: http://localhost:1841
Referer: http://localhost:1841/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the authentication lines and removed method, it works fine now. If there's no authentication don't send in authentication or it'll fail.